# MySQL Federation Issue

Tags: mysql

I am having issue in federating data from remote server into my local machine, my local machine is a virtual machine running mysql server.
I have create a replica of table structure from federated server, using the connection string

---

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts (

    ID     INT(20) NOT NULL default '0',
    AccountNumber   VARCHAR(32)  default NULL,
    Fname   VARCHAR(255) default NULL,
    Sname   VARCHAR(255)  default NULL,
    Mob   VARCHAR(255)  default NULL,  
    Email   VARCHAR(255) default NULL,
    BranchCode   VARCHAR(255) default NULL,  
    ContactType   VARCHAR(5) default NULL, 
    AccountContactable   VARCHAR(5) default NULL
) 
ENGINE=FEDERATED

CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@192.168.??.????:3306/Databasename/Contacts';
```

---

when I run it, I don't get any error, it say table created, but when I check the table it has no data...
can anyone Help please

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you haven't enabled the federated storage engine in your new server? It will give the same effect.

Comment: @MRQ: Use `show engines;` and verify that Engine `FEDERATED` has Support `YES`. If not, you need to enable the federated storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

Because table has no any data, you recently created her, after table was created is empty.

Comment: I am fetching data from another server table into this table, that why used federation at time of creation, is this not how it work??